# DSolve does not give an analytic solution for a tutorial input

Tags: differential-equations, version-10

I am just starting with *Mathematica* and I have tried to solve PDE following [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html), with first three inputs from the Elliptical Partial Differential equations section:

```
leqn = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
bc = u[x, 0] == UnitBox[x];
sol = DSolve[{leqn, bc}, u[x, y], {x, y}]
```

But instead analytic form in the link I have only an echo

```
DSolve[{Derivative[0, 2][u][x, y] + Derivative[2, 0][u][x, y] == 0, u[x, 0] == UnitBox[x]}, u[x, y], {x, y}]
```

I am using *Mathematica 10.0 Student Edition*. Could anybody give me an advice? Thank you.

Sorry for that question, I know that similar topics were discussed here. But I have expected, that the program should work correctly at least for inputs from the tutorial.

Comment: On MMA 10.4 I obtain the output indicated in the docs: [result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/09nCz.png). Just to make sure that it is not something simple, have you tried restarting *Mathematica* and running the code again? If that doesn't work, maybe you should get in touch with Wolfram Support.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have tried restarting *Mathemataica*, but it did not help.

Comment: I am not quite sure, but it seems that analytical solution of partial differential equations are only since 10.3, if not 10.4

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Interesting... The last update to DSolve docs seems to have been done in version 10.3, and it included the example from the OP, so it should work in 10.3 at least. Unfortunately I don't have a previous version to test. Maybe somebody else could chime in on that point.

Comment: OK, thank you both for the answers. I suppose that it is the version problem. I try to look, if we have available new version on our university.

Comment: I knew there was a reason to keep all these old versions on my hard drive.  I can confirm it works for versions 10.3 and after, but not for prior versions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for a capability that does not exist in the version of _Mathematica_ the OP is using.